# Electron does not load index.html correctly, files from local folder are not loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I am trying to run via electron the following web app:

[image]

I am retrieving `index.html` like this:

```
win.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, `/dist/index.html`),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true
    })
  );
```

When executing `electron .`, the app opens but is unable to load any file located in the `assets` folder. Any idea how to fix this?

Here is the error (`net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`):

[image]

My `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
     <link
         rel="stylesheet"
         href="/assets/css/main-83c5c35873.css"
         type="text/css"
     />
     [...]
   </head>
   <body>
       <script src="/assets/js/app-a707f191c1.js"></script>
       <script src="/assets/js/tpls-096dff06b3.js"></script>
       [...]
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should post how they are loaded in the "index.html" file

Comment: @Margon updated

Comment: Where is that script executing? I'd suggest logging `__dirname` to see if it is the directory you think it is.